# How to get users input in a text adventure game (Java/Applet)

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


    class DD {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("#########");
    myFrame.setSize(640,480);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    myFrame.add(textArea);
    new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    //System objects
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean running = true;
    textArea.append("\t\n########################################");
    textArea.append("\t\n>#############");
    textArea.append("\t\n>Th#############11!");
    textArea.append("\t\n>Typ#############enture!");
    textArea.append("\t\n########################################");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("start")){
            { ///beginning of story.
        if(running)
        textArea.append("\t\nYo#############.");
        textArea.append("\t\n#############");
        textArea.append("\t\n1.#############t.");
        textArea.append("\t\n2.G#############t.");
        String input1 = in.nextLine();
        if(input1.equals("1")){
            textArea.append("\n>Y#############");
            textArea.append("\n>#############");
            textArea.append("\n>A#############");
            textArea.append("\n>1.#############");
            textArea.append("\n>2.#############");
        if(input.equals("1")){
                textArea.append("\n>#############");
                textArea.append("\n>#############");
                textArea.append("\n>Ga#############d.");
                    }
        if(input.equals("2")){
                textArea.append("\n>#############");
                textArea.append("\n>#############");
                textArea.append("\n>Y#############ars");
                textArea.append("\n>Y#############");
                    }
        }
        else if(input1.equals("2")){
            textArea.append("\n>Y#############.");
            textArea.append("\n>Y#############.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my text adventure game, i'm stuck on how to get users input. i have read about 'action listener' i don't know how to use it, but i really want the input to be entered like its in a console or terminal/cmd like program. the user just needs to enter 1, 2 or 3 to preform an action.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java

Comment: @Deh I wouldn't think so, I think (or I hope) the OP is trying to use a GUI to get the user input, but they simply don't understand the basic concepts of an event driven environment

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh yes that's right was tricked by the title, then this one may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390503/java-swing-getting-input-from-a-jtextfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump the `Scanner` to start with.  Use a `JTextField`.  You need to understand that you're operating in an event driven environment, this means that you need to make use of the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to be notified when something changes

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: i had scanner on because my game was running in a console in eclipse.

Comment: Well, if you want to use a GUI, then use a GUI.  If you want to use the console, then use the console, not both

Comment: i forgot to remove it, because currently i'm learning to make my game run in the GUI and when i test my game to see if the story is working i use the console and just remove the Jframe code. i'm in the process of making my game stable in a GUI..

Comment: @eels11 The scanner reacts to the user pressing the enter key before something happens, do you want the GUI version with a textfield to do the same? If so: I'd still do a step in between and first make it work by pressing a button and when you've got that working, try to remove the button and make it work by pressing the enter key.

Comment: how do i add a add method? sorry but i'm new to java programming,

Comment: You don't.  Look at the linked tutorials, they show you how to create a `JFrame` and how to add components to a container

Comment: I have been reading the links and they have helped a lot, but i have one problem when i use Frame.pack(); it makes my window small (only the text field shows, until you stretch the window/applet). how would i keep the window the same size (i have tried .setResizable(false))? also .pack(); makes my textfield appear... without it i have no text field in my game

Comment: hopefully this is my last question (i hope i'm not annoying you), my JTextfield covers my whole screen, and i just want it on the top of my screen... i have jt.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING); . i don't know what to try anymore.... (it covers the whole background and grows if i resize the window, its also behind my textArea..)

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, I think you want to add your `JTextArea` to the center position, which is the default position and your `JTextField` to the `SOUTH` (maybe `NORTH`); `frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`, see [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details ;)

Comment: i have made a action listener and i want it to add text to my TextArea. is that possible? (my action listener does nothing right now).

Comment: Yes, `JTextArea#append` would be the best solution (`JTextField#getText` to get the text), but you will need to have access to the components, normally best to use class instance fields

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a leak here:

```
myFrame.add(textArea);
**new JTextArea();**
textArea.setEditable(false);
```

(The line in bold located in the first lines of main, and it needs to be modified or removed)

Regarding your actual Q, I think that since it is meant to be a text based game, you could do something like this to accept user input:

```
(...)

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   (...)
   // create a scanner to read the command-line input
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   bool running = true;

   init();

   //game loop
   while (running)
   {
    if(scanner.next() == 1)
     {
        // do this
     }else if ( == 2)
     {
        // do that
     }//etc
    //and simply change running to false, when you want the game to end
   }
   (...)
}

//this is simply a function to present the initial choices and general info to the user.
   private void init(){System.out.println("Add instructions for the user here, e.g. telling them that they have to press 1,2, or 3");}
```